# How do I see why I got a down-vote in a question where I didn't post anything?

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

My reputation log shows a downvote on [How to achieve code folding effects in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085170/how-to-achieve-code-folding-effects-in-emacs) Why don't I see anything from me on that page. How can I find out what the down-vote is for?

Comment: Do you mean *you* downvoted one of the answers there and lost 1 rep point as a result?

Comment: That's what it was. I couldn't tell from my user info screens, but [the detailed reputation faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238) explained it. Thanks!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I suggest that you move your comment into an answer, so that Simon can accept it and the question can be "answered".

Comment: @Heinzi, you have a point, better to have "resolved" questions even on meta :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you downvoted one of this question's answers, you lost one reputation point and the log will indeed show that loss as a downvote (yours).

The [reputation FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/164403) says:

> #### You lose reputation when:
>
> - you voted an answer *down/not useful*: **−1**

Note that the log actually says `downvoted` if you downvoted someone else, but `downvote` if someone else downvoted you.